# Differentiating between normal webpages and XML pages (feeds)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I googled this question but found nothing related to the topic. Is there any way to differentiate between normal web links and xml links when using beautifulsoup in python?

I actually tried to use feedfinder2, but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test quite extensively but you can try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_file, "xml")
# RSS feeds start with <rss>
if soup.html is None:
    # Do html stuff
else:
    # code that processes the rss
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but actually it, requires another request to the page. I was looking for something that can differentiate by looking at the url. The reason for this is that a page might contain a lot of xml pages and 100 of normal pages. And requesting every single page will be very costly.

Comment: True but then you shouldn't attempt to use ``BeautifulSoup`` at all. I think the best think to do is to reverse engineer the page to see the logic behind the rss instances and look for patterns